# Apply movement corresponding to collision in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision-detection, collision, game-physics

I am working on some collision detection and behaviour with three.js in a 3d space

Let's say I have a player and each time it collides with the object I want the object movement and velocity reaction to correapond to the player hit like so:

[image]

The player is moving using a translation under Z and rotation under Y axis. All I have is the player current velocity and this movement, how would I go about applying the corresponding force and direction to the respective collision?

Comment: I've tried applying the same Z translation according to the player velocity and rotation under Y axis corresponding to player to the objects colliding but not having success with it so far.

Comment: Are you expecting a common advice about how to implement collision detection? Because for now, it's very hard to understand what you're asking about, without seeing your code, even with that illustration. .